# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Flutter

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

Hi there i have published my app on playstore and found this issue in firebase crashlytics and I don’t know what this is about. Please help me fix this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the abiFilters in build.gradle under android/app/build

```
defaultConfig { 
    ndk { 
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a' 
    }
}
```

Documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gc

Comment: This doesn’t solve the problem still same issue and i think it is due to facebook_audience_network